# HTML nested forms using modals using python flask

Tags: python, forms, bootstrap-modal

I am currently working on a project including a lot of forms. I will run into the following problem on numerous occasions throughout my development:

I have an endpoint named /user/new which you can imagine contains a form that will allow a tenant admin to add a new user to the tool:

I also have the option of adding users into groups.

This feature is enabled by allowing the admin to add groups to the user, or to add users to the group in the respective endpoints/forms.

This is all well and good and very easy to implement using wtforms and sqlalchemy.

My issue now comes when I witch to have a small button next to the group field in my user form, that will allow the admin to enable a modal form where he can create a new group.

When clicking OK the modal should close, and the new group should be added to the database, as well as having the group added to the multi select field of the user form.

How would one go about creating such a feature?

Comment: What is specifically your doubt? I would use Ajax to be able to "stack" modals with forms, without losing the data of the previously loaded forms and if a form is saved successfully, trigger an event to refresh the currently loaded forms so they retrieve the new data from the server (or from a form's submission response).

Comment: I am currently experimenting with flask-sijax and are getting nice results. unfourtunately I am using select2 for my select fields, and have no idea how to update these without refreshing the entire page. Another issue is that form validation seem to be off on my modal form, so I need to figure this out too